# Splitting Strings by Container Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

So I am trying to write a program that could be used to analyze DNA, right now I'm trying to split the genes in the "strand." In order for this to happen I need to analyze the strand and split it by one of the three STOP codons (groups of three base pairs). My code as of now goes like this:

```
class Strand:

  def __init__(self, code):
    self.code = [code]
    self.endCodons = []
    self.genes = []

  def getGenes(self):
    for codon in self.endCodons:
      for code in self.code:
        code = code.split(codon)


strand = Strand("ATCATGCACATAGAAACTGATACACACCACAGTGATCACATGAAGTACACATG")
strand.getGenes()
print(strand.genes)
```

However, when I run it, it returns an empty list.
I could use some advice.

Comment: What do you expect your program to do? `self.endCodons` is an empty list, so `getGenes()` won't do anything.

Comment: What are *STOP codons*? you need to put them in your question!

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=stop+codons

Comment: @Kasra: StopCondons - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_codon

Comment: I was hoping to index the results from endCodons and use them to split the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Running a loop through each stop codon and splitting by that will cause incorrect output as I would figure these stop codons can appear in any order in the sequence, and an iteration over the stop codon list will require that the stops are in that same order.

So, if I understand correctly, you will need to scan your string from left to right and search for the codons that way:

```
class Strand:
  def __init__(self, code):
    self.code = code
    self.endCodons = ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]
    self.genes = []

  def getGenes(self):
    if (len(self.code) % 3 != 0):
      print("Input sequence is not divisible by 3?")

    # In this, we assume each stop codon is always 3 characters.
    iteration = 0
    lastGeneEnd = 0
    while (iteration < len(self.code)):
      # What is our current 3 character sequence? (Unless it's at the end)
      currentSequence = self.code[iteration:iteration + 3]

      # Check if our current 3 character sequence is an end codon
      if (currentSequence in self.endCodons):
        # What will our gene length be?
        geneLength = (iteration + 3) - lastGeneEnd

        # Make sure we only break into multiples of 3
        overlap = 3 - (geneLength % 3)
        # There is no overlap if our length is already a multiple of 3
        if (overlap == 3): overlap = 0

        # Modify the gene length to reflect our overlap into a multiple of 3
        geneLength = geneLength + overlap

        # Update the iteration so we don't process any more than we need
        iteration = iteration + overlap + 3

        # Grab the entire gene sequence, including the stop codon
        gene = self.code[lastGeneEnd:iteration]

        # If we have a 3-length gene and there's nothing left, just append to the last gene retrieved as it has
        # got to be part of the last sequence
        if (len(gene) == 3 and iteration >= len(self.code)):
          lastIndex = len(self.genes) - 1
          self.genes[lastIndex] = self.genes[lastIndex] + gene
          break

        # Make sure we update the last end index so we don't include portions of previous positives
        lastGeneEnd = iteration

        # Append the result to our genes and continue
        self.genes.append(gene)

        continue

      iteration = iteration + 1

strand = Strand("ATCATGCACATAGAAACTGATACACACCACAGTGATCACATGAAGTACACATG")
strand.getGenes()
print("Got Genes: ")
print(strand.genes)

for gene in strand.genes:
  print("Sequence '%s' is a multiple of 3: %u" % (gene, len(gene) % 3 == 0))
```

I'm not really a biologist, so I may have made some incorrect assumptions.

**Edits:**

The code guarantees breaks into multiples of threes, but I seem to still not quite understand the desired logic. It does work in the given example, but I am not sure if it works as it should in other situations.

Comment: Your code works great except that it isn't breaking the genes into groups of 3. For instance: "AGTAGATAA" should come out as one gene, however it comes out as: "AGTAG ATAA." It should only break the genes into multiples of 3.

Comment: Ah, alright, I'll correct that (as I did misunderstand exactly how it was supposed to be split).

Comment: It splits into multiples of threes but I don't know if it's exactly what you needed either way. Also it assumes that the input length will always be divisible by three (hence the if checking for any hanging 3-character sequence), is this a correct assumption? It also assumes that you won't encounter a stop codon as the first sequence in the string. (The sequence flows from left to right, so this shouldn't occur?) I think a better example now would be the proper splitting of a longer sequence, such as what was in your original post.

Comment: The strands are split into groups of three called codons which are translated into amino acids. It's extremely important that all codons are 3 base pairs in length.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's what my edited code in the post is ensuring. It splits up by each stop codon and the length of each gene is divisible by three (hence the code that iterates through the genes list afterwards and mods by 3). Forgive me if I'm giving you issues with my misunderstanding of genetic codes.